# MongoDB aggregation $group stage by already created values / variable from outside

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

Imaging I have an array of objects, available before the `aggregate` query:

```
const groupBy = [
  {
    realm: 1,
    latest_timestamp: 1318874398, //Date.now() values, usually different to each other
    item_id: 1234, //always the same
  },
  {
    realm: 2,
    latest_timestamp: 1312467986, //actually it's $max timestamp field from the collection
    item_id: 1234,
  },
  {
    realm: ..., //there are many of them
    latest_timestamp: ...,
    item_id: 1234,
  },
  {
    realm: 10,
    latest_timestamp: 1318874398, //but sometimes then can be the same
    item_id: 1234,
  },
]
```

And collection ([example set available on MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JhFGLEzhUuO)) with the following schema:

```
  {
    realm: Number,
    timestamp: Number,
    item_id: Number,
    field: Number, //any other useless fields in this case
  }
```

My problem is, **how to `$group` the values from the collection via the aggregation framework by using the already available set of data (from groupBy) ?**

### What have been tried already.

Okay, let skip crap ideas, like:

```
for (const element of groupBy) {
  //array of `find` queries
}
```

My current working aggregation query is something like that:

```
      //first stage
      {
         $match: { 
           "item": 1234
           "realm" [1,2,3,4...,10]
         }
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: {
            realm: '$realm',
          },
          latest_timestamp: {
            $max: '$timestamp',
          },
          data: {
            $push: '$$ROOT',
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: '$data',
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          'data.latest_timestamp': {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $eq: ['$data.timestamp', '$latest_timestamp'],
              },
              then: '$latest_timestamp',
              else: '$$REMOVE',
            },
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $replaceRoot: {
          newRoot: '$data',
        },
      },
      //At last, after this stages I can do useful job
```

but I found it a bit obsolete, and I already heard that using `[.mapReduce][1]` could solve my problem a bit faster, than this query. (But official docs doesn't sound promising about it) Does it true?

As for now, I am using 4 or 5 stages, before start working with useful (for me) documents.

### Recent update:

I have checked the [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) stage and I found it curious for this certain case. Probably it will help me out.

### For what it's worth:

After receiving documents after the necessary stages I am building a representative cluster chart, that you may also know [as a heatmap](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap)
[image: Heatmap]

After that I was iterating each document (or array of objects) one-by-one to find their correct *x* and *y* coordinated in place which should be:

```
[
  { 
    x: x (number, actual $price), 
    y: y (number, actual $realm),
    value: price * quantity,
    quantity: sum_of_quantity_on_price_level
  }
]
```

As for now, it's old awful code with for...loop inside each other, but in the future, I will be using `$facet` => `$bucket` operators for that kind of job.

Comment: Not sure I understand what the exact problem is. Is it that this query is too slow and you are looking for a solution, which would perform better?

Comment: Well, some kind of, the real problem is not the performance of the query itself, but that I spent a lot of time and resources finding the `$latest` timestamp for each `$realm` within the collection of 10M+ docs. Which are actually already found, stored, and ready to serve, but unfortunately I don't know how to use them during the *aggregation* `$group` stage. So I want to learn, is there a way to use this data and expand my experience with MongoDB itself. Because I know how to "import" variable for `$match` stage, but have no clue for `$group`

Comment: Ahh, I see, you'd like to use data that's already stored in a variable as a starting point for your query, correct? If so, then this depends on how many groups you have and what you're trying to do with them. If you'd like to split the processing into two parallel pipelines (so each pipeline starts from the same point), you can indeed use `$facet`.

Comment: @Avius, thank you, I also found it useful. If you have used it before, could a bit describe it for me, if I have about 100 or so groups, which exactly the same query, does it "ok" to use?

Comment: Well, what do you want to do with those groups? Could you update your question so that we can see what the final result should look like? Perhaps add the code that goes after `//At last, after this stages I can do useful job` too.

Comment: @Avius done!  It's for building highchairs' heatmap. So each $realm (id value) is coordinate for Y-axis, and price (via future $bucket) will be coordinate for X-axis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224677/discussion-between-avius-and-alexzedim).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have found an answer to my question in another, but relevant way.

I was thinking about using [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) operator and to be honest, it's still an option, but using it, as below is a bad practice.

```
//building $facet query before aggregation

const ObjectQuery = {}
for (const realm of realms) {
  Object.assign(ObjectQuery, { `${realm.name}` : [ ... ] }
}

//mongoose query here
aggregation([{
    $facet: ObjectQuery
  },
  ...
])
```

So, I have chosen a `$project` stage and [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/index.html) operator to filter results, such as $groups do.

Also, using `MapReduce` could also solve this problem, but for some reason, the official Mongo docs [recommends to avoid using it](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/index.html), and choose aggregation: $group and $merge operators instead.